Unexpected mutation of Prop
I am passing an apiStepNumber prop from the parent component to the child component and using it in the child component as a v-model value

NOTE: Code Snippets will not work. Please avoid running them. Snippets are for understanding purposes only

Parent Component
I am calling various APIs inside the parent component and updating the apiNumber data variable as 1 2 3.. so on at successful API calls and passing it as an apiStepNumber prop.

if(firstApiCallSuccessful) this.apiNumber = 2;
if(secondApiCallSuccessful) this.apiNumber = 3;
..so on



<child-component :apiStepNumber="apiNumber"></child-component>



Child Component
( I am using the apiStepNumber prop as v-model value and other basic calculations but getting an error as "Unexpected mutation of 'apiStepNumber' prop" at
v-model="apiStepNumber" )


<script>
export default {
    props: {
        apiStepNumber: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            steps: [
                { id: 1, text: "Emailing the Link" },
                { id: 2, text: "Getting Details" },
                { id: 3, text: "Extracting Data" },
                { id: 4, text: "Validating Data" },
                { id: 5, text: "Almost there..." },
                { id: 6, text: "All Done!" },
            ],
        };
    },
}
</script>
<v-stepper v-model="apiStepNumber" vertical>
  <v-stepper-step
    v-for="(item, i) in steps"
    :key="item.id"
    :complete="apiStepNumber > i + 1"
    :step="i + 1"
    :color="apiStepNumber > i + 1 ? 'success' : 'primary'"
  >{{ item.text }}</v-stepper-step>
</v-stepper>



What I tried

Saving the prop value in the local data variable inside the child component and use that local variable rather than the prop directly, but that does not meet my requirement.
Tried looking at other posts on StackOverflow, on this topic but was not able to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

There's "code" format in editor. There's no need to use snippets if they are non-workable, especially if this requires to comment on this

Sure will edit it accordingly. Thanks !

As the error says, props cannot be mutated. Unless there's a need for a child to have its own state (e.g. to undo changes) it needs a parent to apply all changes to the state, this is the way two-way binding works.
A child needs to emit an event on changes. For Vue 2, v-model convention can be followed like:
<v-stepper
  :value="modelValue"
  @input="$emit('input', $event)"
>

apiStepNumber needs to be renamed to apiNumber the convention:
props: {
    value: {
         ...

A parent could use <child v-model="apiNumber"> to receive values from input event.

It's called apiNumber in the question, so it's likely  in your case

Thanks! Also please let me know if we need to rename it on parent component while passing it as a prop.

This is how it's renamed in a parent,  instead of  . And in a child it's props: { modelValue : {..... See the docs https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#basic-usage . The use of v-model presumes "modelValue" prop by default

Thanks for the help. I tried to implement your solution and it resolves the issue of mutation but somehow I am not getting the desired functionality I was looking with this in my project whereas when I removed the v-model and used v-bind and value attributes it gave me the desired results without any warning or error about the mutation of prop.

@HarshShukla Can you clarify what it looks like? The question doesn't contain vue version tag. In case it's v2 you'll have to replace all mentions of "modelValue" with "value"

I am sorry, I forgot to mention the version. Yes, it is v2 and not v3, can you suggest changes according to v2 if possible? I will try that and let you know if it is working or not.

I updated. You can use any prop and event names, it's just a value+input combo allows to shorten it to v-model in a parent
